# Wikidata SPARQL multiple filters

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am trying to find cast members who appear together in different films.

For example:

- "Find all the actors who appeared in Empire Strikes Back and Temple of Doom" should return Harrison Ford.
- "Find all the actors who appeared in Empire Strikes Back and Return of the Jedi" should return Harrison Ford, Carrie Fisher, Mark Hamill etc.

This gets all the Temple of Doom actors:

```
SELECT ?actor ?actorLabel WHERE {
  ?movie wdt:P161 ?actor .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
  FILTER(?movie = wd:Q179215)
}
LIMIT 100
```

I would have thought I could change the filter to be

`FILTER(?movie = wd:Q179215 && ?movie = wd:Q181795)`

but that doesn't return any items.

I've tried using

```
select ?actor ?actorLabel where {
  ?actor wdt:P106 wd:Q33999 .
   wd:Q181795 wdt:P161 ?actor .
   wd:Q181803 wdt:P161 ?actor .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}
```

But that misses out lots of actors.  Even just doing it with a single film only returns an incomplete cast list.

Comment: `&&` is the conjunction operator, that means logical `and` - this doesn't make sense, right? Nothing can have two different values. You have to use logical `or` expressed by `||` - but that's not what you want. The second query is indeed the way to go and is correct, it returns all actors that played in both films. What's wrong with the result? Which actor is missing in your opinion? You want all actors that played in both films, right? Or do you mean in either of those films? Then use `||` or even better `VALUES ?film{wd:Q181795 wd:Q181803} ?film wdt:P161 ?actor .`

Comment: I see. Running the second query misses out Carrie Fisher and Mark Hamill. And several others who are in both films.

Comment: Ok, got it. The problem is, not every actor has the occupation actor in Wikidata. For example, open `https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q108941` in the browser. She has the occupation "film actor" which is a subtype of actor. Just remove the first triple pattern ` ?actor wdt:P106 wd:Q33999 .`

Comment: or you do `select distinct ?actor ?actorLabel where {
  ?actor wdt:P106/wdt:P279* wd:Q33999 .
   wd:Q181795 wdt:P161 ?actor .
   wd:Q181803 wdt:P161 ?actor .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
} ` to get all people that have occupation actor or a subtype of actor. The important part here is `wdt:P106/wdt:P279*` which is called *property path* in SPARQL 1.1

Comment: @AKSW that's perfect! I'm happy to accept that as an answer if you want to post it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The operator you are expecting is **OR** not **AND**.

Try using

> FILTER(?movie = wd:Q179215 || ?movie = wd:Q181795)

Comment: That doesn't work. That picks up actors who *are* in the 1st movie but are *not* in the 2nd.

Comment: You should try INTERSECTION operation.